# Edit model with virtual field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Shop` model which contains several fields. One of which is a `virtual User` one. Whenever I try to edit one entry I get an error saying that `User` field is required.

```
public class Shop
{
    //..
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    //..
}
```

My workaround is this:

```
        shop.User = shop.User; //re-set the value
        shop.Active = true;
        db.Entry(restaurant).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

And I have to do this for all the fields. Is this the standard approach for this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to this:

```
public class Shop
{
    //..
    public int UserId {get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    //..
}
```

Entity Framework will automatically detect that `UserId` is the foreign key for object `User`. You had this problem because `User` is virtual (lazy loaded). When changing the model without accessing or setting this property EF thinks it's empty (I assume). The foreign key `UserId` is not virtual, and will be fetched together with the other properties of model `Shop`, so you don't have to re-set the value when saving the model.

To set a new user, you now have to do for example:

```
myShop.UserId = 1; // instead of setting myShop.User
```

For more information, see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Well, I modified a bunch of models to reflect this, ran the `Seed` function for about an hour and in the end the exact same error.

Comment: By the way, maybe it's because the `UserId` field is a `string` and not `int`?

Comment: If your `User` model's primary key is an int, then `Shop.UserId` should be an int as well. But what kind of seed method do you use when it runs for an hour?

Comment: Yes, I know. Thank you. In my case both classes had a `string` primary and foreign key. I said maybe that's the cause that your model worked and mine didn't. My seed function reads around 500 entities from database, inserts them in database and for each of them a few child ones. It's a little complicated and I should have all of them in production to test full features.